# In a monarchy, what detemines the title owned by a monarch

Tags: monarchy

Is there anything that determines whenever a ruling monarch is a count, marquis, duke, archduke, prince, king, or anything else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tradition.  Entirely tradition.

Wikipedia has a page on [every royal title](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_and_noble_ranks), which also includes the note:

> Several ranks were widely used (for more than a thousand years in Europe alone) for both sovereign rulers and non-sovereigns. Additional knowledge about the territory and historic period is required to know whether the rank holder was a sovereign or non-sovereign.

It's also complicated by the fact that titles in different languages don't necessarily have direct equivalents in others.  Tsar is a great example: It comes from the Latin *caesar*, but there is no modern English title that derives from *caesar*.  I think it's usually matched to "Emperor" when it's not used as-is, but that comes from the Latin *imperator*.

Looking it over, my impression is that whether you were a Prince, Duke, King or Emperor (or their local equivalents) depended on how big the territory you claimed was (in ascending order).  If you were first among relative equals, you might be a Grand Prince, Grand Duke/Archduke, or King of Kings.

Wikipedia [also has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_sovereign_monarchs) of the remaining sovereign monarchs and their titles, which include Kings, Queens, Princes, Grand Dukes, Sultans, and Emirs (and a few others).

Comment: You forgot "[Supreme Leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leaders_of_North_Korea)"

Comment: @DVK - That's not a monarchy, though.  Although it *would* be ironic if a "**Democratic** People's **Republic**" stated it was a **monarchy** while actually being a **dictatorship**, they call themselves socialist.

Comment: Ok, so basically the only meaning of those titles is a distant latin word.

Comment: @Bregalad - Pretty much. Titles are pretty arbitrary, and there's lots of historical examples of rulers going "I now proclaim that I'm _______".  There is something of a hierarchy to them, but there's no direct relation to how much is *actually* ruled.  Also, not every title comes from Latin specifically, but you've got the idea right.

Comment: @Bobson - I'm curious in what way it can be rejected to be a monarchy? Absolute rule passed to descendant, sounds like one to me.

Comment: @DVK - In the specific sense, because they don't say they're a monarchy or act like one. For example, they hold elections for their leader, even if there's no question about who gets elected. But in the general sense, there's other traits of even an [absolute monarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_monarchy) which they don't show: there aren't other strong power blocs which are nominally-but-not-always-actually subservient, there's no claim of divine right, and there's no *presumption* of hereditary rule (no designated heir).  None of those are required, but they're all characteristic.

Comment: @DVK: This would be its own distinct question on its own. There is many difference between an single party totalitarist dictatorship and a monarchy. The main differences that comes to mind is that a monarchy do not follow an ideology, and that the monarch itself has to follow some traditional rules and laws, and that there is no leading party in a monarchy.

Comment: @Bregalad - "monarchy do not follow an ideology" - I really doubt that's accurate. Ditto "no leading party" - they may not call it that, but a political grouping led by the monarch always exists. They used to be called "Nobles" :)

Comment: @DVK - Actually, the nobles are  the "nominally-but-not-always-actually subservient" power bloc I mentioned. Regardless, Bregalad is right that this is really developing into a good new question and shouldn't stay in comments.

Comment: @Bobson - Yes, I agree :) http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/is-kim-supreme-leader-dynasty-in-north-corea-a-monarchy-from-polysci-definition

Comment: @user4012 I think "a monarchy do not follow an ideology" means there is established traditional authority in the monarchy itself, regardless of the ideologies of the individuals comprising it. Whereas in a totalitarian single-party rule, a potential heir with very different ideology would probably be expelled from the party and thus illegitimate. Queens Mary I and Elizabeth I of England come to mind; Mary attempting to re-establish Catholicism as the state religion of England, and then Elizabeth changing course again. Their authority came from their claims of rightful descent, not ideology.